# Python list to iterate two elements

Tags: python

I'm working on project [Euler problem 18](http://projecteuler.net/problem=18).

I have the structure below. How can I multiply or concatenate the input lists that set this structure, to achieve the output at the bottom. I have tried using `while` loop but unable to achieve following result.is there any way I can achieve this using iterators or any possible way.

I don't want any code but some guidance would help me achieve some result.

This is the structure.

```
 75
 1 2
1 2 3
```

to find the solution I figured that i want to pass through each node. so first node is 75. 75 pass through 1,2 it becomes 75,1 and 75,2  now in third level.(75,1) can pass through 1,2 and (75,2) can pass through 2,3 resulting possible routes as (75,1,1),(75,1,2),(75,2,2),(75,2,3)

I took them as list to present small example. but unable to append like that.
This is how I represent the structure above:

```
a=[75]
b=[1,2]
c=[1,2,3]
```

So then, I'm aiming to achieve

```
#first loop:
     [[75,1],[75,2]]
#second loop:
     [[75,1,1],[75,1,2],[75,2,2],[75,2,3]]
```

So while you can go from 75 to 1 to 2 (line 1 to 2 to 3), you can't go from 75 to 1 to 3 (the latter step is too large).

Comment: What is the basis of this? I don't see a pattern

Comment: @sshashank124 i have updated question.still u want http://projecteuler.net/problem=18 pls refer this i want to achieve that though there are other numbers concept is same

Comment: pls down voter if u want data i would provide.pls dont down vote.that cause ban i cant futher ask question to learn. this my seconda ccount due to ban

Comment: I didn't downvote... Just asking the question

Comment: If you dont want to get downvoted, ask a good question. Even after your edit and looking at the euler page, i still dont get what you are asking

Comment: @TimCastelijns to find the solution i figured that i want to pass through each node. so first node is 75. 75 pass through 1,2 it becomes 75,1 and 75,2 next same (75,1) can pass through 1,2 in next level

Comment: @TimCastelijns dnt look at numbers in euler and this . but the concept is same. i need pass through all possible nodes

Comment: @TimCastelijns is the question good now

Comment: Complaining about downvotes won't help your cause. I'll attempt to edit your question.

Comment: @sshashank124 can u remove the first comment pls . every one simply down voting seeing ur comment

Comment: @Evert i am new. i low in English. u can. help new users

Comment: However, to get an answer, it would be good if you also provide code. Even though it's code that hasn't worked for you yet. It makes it easier to point out mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive approach might be helpful

```
a=[75]
b=[1, 2]
c=[1, 2, 3]

def dfs(i, j, l):
    if i==len(t):
        ll.append(l)
    elif j==len(t[i])-1:
        dfs(i+1, j, l+[t[i][j]])
    else:
        dfs(i+1, j, l+[t[i][j]])
        dfs(i+1, j+1, l+[t[i][j+1]])

t=[a, b, c]
ll=[]
dfs(0, 0, [])
print ll
```